# How many ways are there to order a baseball lineup with a restriction?

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification

Problem:
Suppose that we have a baseball team with $9$ players. Due to union rules, the person playing first base must bat before the person playing second basemen. How many possible batting orders are there?
Answer:
Let $c$ be the count we seek. For the special case that the person playing first
base bats first then we have $8!$ ways to order the players. If the person playing
first base bats second, then the
number of possible batting orders is $7(7!)$. If the person playing first base bats
third, then the number of possible batting orders is $7(6)(6!)$.  If the person
paying first base bats in the $8$th position, then the number of possible batting orders is $7!$.
\begin{align*}
c &= 7(7!) + 7(6)(6!) + 7(6)(5)(5!) + (7)(6)(5)(4)(4!) + 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(3!) \\
 &+ 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(2!) +  7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)(1!) + 7! \\
%
c &= 7(5040) + 7(6)(720) + 7(6)(5)(120) + (7)(6)(5)(4)(24) + 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(6) \\
 &+ 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(2) +  7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1) + 7! \\
%
c &= 90720 + (7)(6)(5)(4)(24) + 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(6) \\
 &+ 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(2) +  7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1) + 7! \\
%
c &= 126000 + 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(2) +  7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1) + 5040 \\
c &= 126000 + 42(20)(3)(2)(2) +  42(20)(3)(2) + 5040 \\
c &= 126000 + 10080 +  5040 + 5040 \\
c &= 146160
\end{align*}
Is my solution correct?

Based upon the comments I have received. I have updated my solution.

Let $c$ be the count we seek. For the special case that the person playing first
base bats first then we have $8!$ ways to order the players. If the person playing
first base bats second, then the
number of possible batting orders is $7(7!)$. If the person playing first base bats
third, then the number of possible batting orders is $7(6)(6!)$.  If the person
paying first base bats in the $8$th position, then the number of possible batting orders is $7!$.
\begin{align*}
c &= 7(7!) + 7(6)(6!) + 7(6)(5)(5!) + (7)(6)(5)(4)(4!) + 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(3!) \\
 &+ 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(2!) +  7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)(1!) + 8! \\
%
c &= 7(5040) + 7(6)(720) + 7(6)(5)(120) + (7)(6)(5)(4)(24) + 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(6) \\
 &+ 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(2) +  7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1) + 8! \\
%
c &= 90720 + (7)(6)(5)(4)(24) + 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(6) \\
 &+ 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(2) +  7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1) + 8! \\
%
c &= 126000 + 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(2) +  7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1) + 8! \\
c &= 126000 + 7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(2) +  7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1) + 40320 \\
c &= 126000 + 42(20)(12) +  42(20)(6) + 40320 \\
c &= 181440
\end{align*}

Is my solution correct?

Another approach, that was suggested to me, is:
\begin{align*}
c &= \dfrac{9!}{2} = 9(8)(7)(6)(5)(4)(3) \\
c &= 72(42)(20)(3) \\
c &= 181440
\end{align*}

Comment: Not quite:  Your $c=\cdots$ ends with an extra $7!$ for no obvious reason since you already have $7(6)(5)(4)(3)(2)(1)(1!)$, but is missing the $8!$ you mention earlier.  Correcting this would give you the correct answer, though "half of them" i.e. $\frac{9!}{2}$ would be quicker

Answer (score 3):

- There are $9!$ unconstrained ways of arranging the batting lineup.
- P(person playing first base plays before person playing second base) = $\frac12$
- Thus "good" arrangements $ =\frac12\cdot9!$

Answer (score 2):

I see two mistakes. You missed adding $8!$ and you have $7!$ terms twice. Once you fix those, you get the answer of $181440$.

A simpler way is to note that there are $9!$ ways to arrange nine players and due to symmetry, in half of them the first baseman will be ahead of the second baseman. So that leads to the answer of $~\dfrac{9!}{2!}$.

Alternatively, place both first and second baseman in the right order to bat and now pick players from the remaining seven one by one. The first player from the remaining seven will have a choice of $3$ places to bat - before both first baseman and second baseman, after first baseman or after both of them. The next player will have $4$ choices and so on. That leads to an answer of $3 \cdot 4 \cdot 5 \cdot 6 \cdot 7 \cdot 8 \cdot 9 = 181440$.